# How to make a 'get' method for returning a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, accessor

Hello all I'm to return a particular JButton to then later setText on it.
Here is a snippet of the code:

```
JButton[][] tiles = new JButton[4][4];
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
        tiles[i][j] = new JButton();
    }   
}
```

I would basically like to return this JButton using an accessor method.

```
public JButton getJButton(int i, int j) {   
    return JButton[i][j];   
}
```

This is my current idea however that is currently returning null, any ideas on a solution?

Many thanks.

Comment: Change it to: return tiles[i][j];

Comment: thanks, my current issue is that I cannot use this method outside the class as it returns this: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getJButton(int, int) from the type TileBoard, however declaring it static causes it to return null. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`private JButton[][] tiles;` should be a field variable

In you constructor do `tiles = new JButton[4][4]; for...`

And then change you get method to:

```
public JButton getJButton(int i, int j) {   
    return tiles[i][j];   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

declare

```
JButton[][] tiles = null;

public void init() {
    tiles = new JButton[4][4];
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            tiles[i][j] = new JButton();
        }   
    }
}

public JButton getJButton(int i, int j) {   
    return tiles[i][j];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, a new issue has arisen however: if I try to call this method from another class the error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getJButton(int, int) from the type TileBoard. And the only solution offered is to make the get method a static, which makes this solution not work, any ideas?

Comment: declare JButton[][] tiles = null   to  static JButton[][] tiles = null;  it solve your problem.

Comment: This now just returns null, not the correct JButton.

Comment: Make sure that you have initialised the JButton array before calling the getter..     also check that JButton[][] tiles is not declared local variable in init() method..